# Adding a radio value to a multiplication of two values to create a total jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little new to JS and JQuery so any help would be appreciated.

I have the below code which generates a total based on multiplying the value of the top radio button by the value of the slider (based on the defined array). this is value * phone.

I am now looking to add the value of the second radio button to this total so it would be something like (value * phone) + mins. I have tried various different things but cant figure it out.

```js
let $slider = $('#slider'),
    $legend = $('#legend'),
    $total = $('#total'),
    sub = 0,
    sum = 0, 
    lines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20];
    
    
/// SLIDER AND LABEL

lines.forEach( (value, key) => {
  let oneBig = 100 / (lines.length - 1);
  let width = (key === 0 || key === lines.length -1) ? 
              oneBig / 2 : oneBig;
  let text = (key !== lines.length - 1) ?
              value + ' <br>lines' : value + '+ <br>lines';
  let label = $('<label/>')
                .css({ 'width': width + '%'})
                .html(text);
  $legend.append(label);
});



// SUM BEGIN 


$(":radio").on("change", function(){
  let index = $slider.slider("option", "value"),
    phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
      mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val(),
      value = lines[index];
     
  sum = value * phone;
  $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
});

$slider.slider(
  {
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 8,
    step: 1,
    create: () => {
      let value = lines[$slider.slider('value')],
        phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
        mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val();
      
      sum = value * phone;
      $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
    },
    slide: (events, ui) => {
      let value = lines[ui.value],
      phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
      mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val();
      
      sum = value * phone;
      $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
  }
);
```

```css
h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#slider label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#slider {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.lines {
    font-size:10px;
  
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight:bold;
}
label:first-child {
    text-align:left;
}
label:last-child {
    text-align:right;
}

.slide-col #slider a {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #1b2a3d;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="5.99" checked/>option 1
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="9.99" />option 2
<input class="qty1" name="phone" type="radio" value="7.99" />option 3


<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>

<br><br>

<input class="qty2" name="mins" type="radio" value="2.49" checked/>500 mins
<input class="qty2" name="mins" type="radio" value="3.99" />1000 mins
<input class="qty2" name="mins" type="radio" value="5.99" />5000 mins
<input class="qty2" name="mins" type="radio" value="9.99" />7500 mins
<input class="qty2" name="mins" type="radio" value="14.99" />10000 mins



<br>
<br>
<h3>Your total is: £<span id="total">0.00</span></h3>
```

Comment: What issues you getting if you doing (phone*value)+mins ? something like... Uncaught TypeError: sum.toFixed is not a function ?

Comment: When I do  sum = (value * phone); the total appears with the 2 numbers next to each other. 

For example. If value * phone was £23.49 and mins was £2.49, the toal would show as £23.492.49

Comment: Perfect! Follow to my recent answer and let me know if you still having issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool!

Your code has not any critical bugs at all!

In fact all values must be converted to float type before executing calculations.

So, to convert the values to Float, you need to use a javascript function `parseFloat(var)` everywhere in file as below...

```
let $slider = $('#slider'),
$legend = $('#legend'),
$total = $('#total'),
sub = 0,
sum = 0,
lines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 15, 20];

/// SLIDER AND LABEL
lines.forEach( (value, key) => {
  let oneBig = 100 / (lines.length - 1);
  let width = (key === 0 || key === lines.length -1) ?
              oneBig / 2 : oneBig;
  let text = (key !== lines.length - 1) ?
              value + ' <br>lines' : value + '+ <br>lines';
  let label = $('<label/>')
                .css({ 'width': width + '%'})
                .html(text);
  $legend.append(label);
});

// SUM BEGIN
$(":radio").on("change", function(){
  let index = $slider.slider("option", "value"),
    phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
    mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val(),
    value = lines[index];

  sum = parseFloat(value * phone) + parseFloat(mins);
  $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
});

$slider.slider(
  {
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 8,
    step: 1,
    create: () => {
      let value = lines[$slider.slider('value')],
            phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
            mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val();

      sum = parseFloat(value * phone) + parseFloat(mins);
      $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
    },
    slide: (events, ui) => {
      let value = lines[ui.value],
      phone = $("input[name='phone']:checked").val(),
      mins = $("input[name='mins']:checked").val();
      sum = parseFloat(value * phone) + parseFloat(mins);
      $total.text(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
  }
);
```

No additional changes required

Cheers!!

Comment: YES! thank you. So simple when you know the answer haha